# Replace plus, double quotes and spaces except spaces surrounded by double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such text `text + " " + getIncrementedNumber()`. I want to replace to empty string the following characters via JavaScript: `+`, `"` and all spaces **except** that spaces, which are surounded by double quotes. Examples of input and output, which I want to achieve:

- input: `text + " " + getIncrementedNumber()`;

  output: `text getIncrementedNumber()`
- input: `text + "WhateveR" + getIncrementedNumber()`;

  output: `textWhateveRgetIncrementedNumber()`
- input: `text +"Lorem ipsuM"+ getIncrementedNumber()`;

  output: `textLorem ipsuMgetIncrementedNumber()`

I am trying with these RegExps:

- `sourceText.replace( /\+|\s|\b"(.*?)\b"/g, '' )`, which results in `'text""getIncrementedNumber()'`
- `sourceText.replace( /\+|\s|\"(.*?)\"/g, '' )`, which results in `'textgetIncrementedNumber()'`

So I have a problem with excluding replacing spaces in between double quotes.

Comment: will you have any nested quotes, escaped or otherwise?

Comment: No, nothing nested nor escaped.

Comment: in that case, i would replace all the quoted spaces with `#` or something else non-present, then replace the quote parts, then turn `#` into spaces. breaking it up simplifies the logic

Comment: I need to have double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
/\s*\+\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\+\s*/g
```

Snippet:

```js
var s = 'text +"Lorem ipsuM"+ getIncrementedNumber()';
s = s.replace(/\s*\+\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\+\s*/g, "$1");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thank You. Why `"$1"` is used instead of just `""` as replaced value?

Comment: `"$1"` corresponds to whatever was matched between the parentheses inside the regular expression, otherwise the part between quotes would be lost. Now it is retained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/[+"]|[ \t]+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/gm, '');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CIEh0k/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[+"]`: Match `+` or `:`
- `|`: OR
- `[ \t]+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`: Match a space or tab that is outside the quotes by using a lookahead to assert even number of quotes ahead.